# Problem wiht wrong file format (gif insted of jpg) when saving images from server - PHP

Tags: php, image, jpeg, gif, save

I am using this peace of PHP code to save and rename some images.

```
foreach ($phones as &$value)
{
    $link_img =
    $handle = @fopen($link_img, "r");

    if ($handle) 
    {
        while (!feof($handle)) 
        {
            $buffer .= fgets($handle, 4096);
        }

        fclose($handle);
        $filename = "files/nokia_".$phone_model.".jpg";
        $mystring = fopen($filename, "wb");
        $handle = fopen($filename, "wb");
        $numbytes = fwrite($handle, $buffer);
        fclose($handle);
        unset($buffer);
    }
}
```

most of images are JPGs, i think that all files have extension .jpg, but one image I bump in to, have .jpg extension, but its gif (i think), ...

and then my foreach stops :(

how to handle that ?

thanks for your help, I learned much here at stackoverflow, and this is my first question.

Comment: You're not providing enough information! What is `$link_img`? Where do you use $value? Why is .jpg hard coded? What is it you want to tell us about jpg and gif (you think)? What do you mean with your loop stops? How? What error message?

Comment: $link_img is location of image, http://domain.com/img/example.jpg

$value is set of attributes from where I get my data, including link of image, and $phone_model

.jpg is hard coded because I had information that all images are JPGs, I check it quickly and I mostly sow that all have *.jpg extension, now I see even they have it, there are at least one :) which is for sure gif

I don't get error message, it simply stops, I have 42 new entries in my new database, and 41 image, so I guess it stopped when something got went wrong with image.

sorry if my English is not perfect. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is update the following line:

```
$filename = "files/nokia_".$phone_model.".jpg";
```

To:

```
$filename = 'files/nokia_' . $phone_model . str_replace('jpeg', 'jpg', image_type_to_extension(exif_imagetype($link_img)));
```

I don't think this is the reason why your `foreach` loop is stopping though.

Comment: seam that I don't have this function, trying with this right now http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php#80383

Comment: now it works, and stops at different image, ... extension is not a problem, you were right.

Comment: @Nemanja: Try placing `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of your file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [fileinfo functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) instead of guessing what type the images are.